# Matlab script gets stuck when run from command line

Tags: linux, matlab

I have a matlab function that I am calling from the command line:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop -r "matrix(10,'test')"
```

where `matrix.m` contains the following:

```
function y=matrix(N,name)

A = randn(N);
[Q, R] = qr(A);

clearvars A R

ind = randperm(N);
indMinus = ind(1:round(N/2));

diagonal = ones(1,N);
diagonal(indMinus) = -1;

L = diag(diagonal);

mt = Q*L*(Q');

clearvars Q L 

fname = ['matrix',name,'.dat'];

fid = fopen(fname, 'w');
fprintf(fid,'%g\n',N);
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
    fprintf(fid,'%g\n',mt(i,j));
    end
end

quit
```

When I run this command, matlab fails to launch fully, and gets stuck at this state:

```
$     matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop -r "matrix(10,'test')"

                                                   < M A T L A B (R) >
                                         Copyright 1984-2016 The MathWorks, Inc.
                                          R2016a (9.0.0.341360) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                                                    February 11, 2016
```

The weird thing is that this wasn't happening an hour ago. I did not change the code in any way. There is ample system memory. When I run the following instead:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop
```

it launches matlab properly:

```
$ matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop 

                                                   < M A T L A B (R) >
                                         Copyright 1984-2016 The MathWorks, Inc.
                                          R2016a (9.0.0.341360) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                                                    February 11, 2016


For online documentation, see http://www.mathworks.com/support
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.


Academic License

>>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Restart your OS and try again?

Comment: Are you working on a network share and having some locking or connectivity issue when writing the output .dat?

Comment: @tim I don't have direct access to the node, but I'll contact our system administration.

Comment: @AlexanderKemp It is a node that I'm accessing remotely, but the output is written into the local drive. I can also run other (non-matlab) codes that write files to the disk without a problem.